# Data bind in button click event

Tags: angular, syncfusion

I'm using EJ2 Sync Fusion Charts with Angular 6 to create a scatter chart.

.html file

```
 <ejs-chart id="chart-container">
<e-series-collection>
      <e-series [dataSource]="series1" typeof="Scatter"name="Male"></e-series>
       <e-series [dataSource]="series2" typeof="Scatter" name="Female"></e-series>
  </e-series-collection>
</ejs-chart>
<div>
  <button ejs-button (click)="PlotChart()">Draw</button>
</div>
```

.ts File

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartData } from '../chartdata.service';

   export class ScatterComponent implements OnInit {

    public series1: Object;
    public series2: Object;
    public title: string;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(): void {

     // this.PlotChart(); //-> this works!!
    }

    public PlotChart(): void {

      this.title = 'Height Vs Weight';
      this.series1 = ChartData.prototype.getScatterData().series1;
      this.series2 = ChartData.prototype.getScatterData().series2;

    }
  }
```

I'm using an external class(i.e. ChartData) to fetch data to my chart series.
And if I invoke the PlotChart() method inside **ngOnInit** lifecycle hook the chart draws and it will not draw if it was directly triggered by the button click.
Please note that data is still being retrieved as expected in both cases.
It seems to me that chart series are not bounded unless it is called inside the ngOnInit().

title parameter binding works but the chart series binding only not working.

Would anyone tell me a solution for this?

Comment: can you create stackblitz with some data what you have to bind

Comment: Try to put some `console.log` and click few time to debug and what is `ejs-button`  directive, try to remove it and check again?

Comment: @Sanoj_V Thank you for the reply and here is the link for sample data
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wtjggp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchart.service.ts

Comment: @RitwickDey: Thank you for your time but it didn't work either.

Comment: @Lakshitha where is the html code.

Comment: @Sanoj_V That is all the HTML code. I have eliminated axis binding and other bindings for the simplicity. Please find this link to entire changes https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wtjggp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fscatter%2Fscatter.component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution as follows. The problem was chart had not been refreshed after setting the data source to the chart series. Below is the modified code.

.html

```
  <ejs-chart #chart id="chart-container">
<e-series-collection>
      <e-series [dataSource]="series1" typeof="Scatter"name="Male"></e-series>
       <e-series [dataSource]="series2" typeof="Scatter" name="Female"></e-series>
  </e-series-collection>
</ejs-chart>
<div>
  <button ejs-button (click)="PlotChart()">Draw</button>
</div>
```

Change: Added #chart to access the chart element in a component class

Following are the changes in component class.

```
   import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

        export class ScatterComponent {
          @ViewChild('chart')
          public chart: Chart;

         public PlotChart(): void {

         this.chart.series[0].dataSource = ChartData.prototype.getScatterData().series1;
            this.chart.series[1].dataSource = ChartData.prototype.getScatterData().series2;
            this.chart.refresh();
               }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

We are glad to announce that we have resolved the issue "chart data source not binding on refresh method" in the latest syncfusion Esstential Studio Volume 2 main release.

```
<div align='center'>
    <ejs-chart style='display:block;'>            
    </ejs-chart>
</div>
```

Please find the below sample for your reference,
[sample demo link](http://plnkr.co/edit/99RlwqHOBx3uShJp2dtV?p=preview)

Screenshot:

Before button click
[image: Before button click]

After button click
[image: After button click]